# How to not split words

Tags: dash

I have a list of commands in a file called `cmds`, one command per line.

I want to grab the last command, set it in a variable `last_command` and run it later. with `$last_command` or `"$last_command"`, or whatever is more appropriate.

I start by getting the last command:

```
$ last_command="$(cat cmds | tail -1)"
$ echo $last_command
cat file1 file2 file\ 3
```

The last line of `cmds` was `cat cat file1 file2 file\ 3`.

The problem is, when I run `"$last_command"`, it will not know that the space between `file` and `3` is part of the file name and give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your commands in file are correct and have all required spaces escaped evil `eval` will help you. Instead of `$last_command` execute this one:

```
eval $last_command
```

PS. `eval` normally is not considered as best practices as it easily might lead to security issues.